# What is Data Relationship In marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud

I understand that data relationship connects data extensions with each other but what is it's use?

Answer (score 3):

Data Relationships have a single purpose in Marketing Cloud. They allow you to create Filters/Filtered Data Extensions where the selection criteria includes attributes of tables other than the Data Extension being filtered.

For example, in the example below there has been a Data Relationship defined that's called "Account" and that relates the Contact_Salesforce Data Extension and the Account_Salesforce Data Extension. Thanks to the Data Relationship, you can filter Contact_Salesforce records based on related Account_Salesforce attributes... In this example we're filtering based on the Account's "Account_Age__c" field.

[image]